# Extract array of element from rendered component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am developing spfx web part for SharePoint Online using `React` and pnp controls

I am using pnp control **Carousel**

URL for the actual control: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/blob/master/docs/documentation/docs/controls/Carousel.md

```
<Carousel
  buttonsLocation={CarouselButtonsLocation.top}
  buttonsDisplay={CarouselButtonsDisplay.block}

  contentContainerStyles={styles.carouselContent}
  containerButtonsStyles={styles.carouselButtonsContainer}

  isInfinite={true}

  element={this.carouselElements}
  onMoveNextClicked={(index: number) => { console.log(`Next button clicked: ${index}`); }}
  onMovePrevClicked={(index: number) => { console.log(`Prev button clicked: ${index}`); }}
/>
```

In above control  element={this.carouselElements}

property needs array of element distinguished based on the 'key' property

Now I have created another component which renders as below:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IHomePageCarouselProps> {
    return (
      <div className={styles.homePageCarousel}>
        {/* <div className="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-banner "> */}
        <div key="1">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/banner_1.jpg " alt="banner" className="rounded-top" />
          </a>
          <div className="bg-white rounded-bottom p-10">
            <span className="font-color-green font-weight-bold ">
              News title will show here. News title will show here. News title will show
              here. News title will show here. News title will show here. News title will
              show here. News title will show here. News title will show here. ...
                </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div key="2">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/banner_1.jpg " alt="banner" className="rounded-top" />
          </a>
          <div className="bg-white rounded-bottom p-10">
            <span className="font-color-green font-weight-bold ">
              News title will show here. News title will show here. News title will show
              here. News title will show here. News title will show here. News title will
              show here. News title will show here. News title will show here. ...
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* </div> */}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

using above component in Carousel element property as below:

```
element={<HomePageCarousel />}
```

but `HomePageCarousel` cannot render without main `div` which is the requirement of `React`. Can somebody help me how can I output or extract array of elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading through the [documentation](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/blob/master/docs/documentation/docs/controls/Carousel.md#how-to-use-this-control-in-your-solutions) for `element` property which states:

> Fixed array of elemenets to be displayed in carousel - if triggerPageEvent is not used. In case triggerPageEvent is in use, JSX.Element has to be provided. Elements are distinguished based on the 'key' property.

And because the `element` is required then type what you must pass there can be `JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]`.

So based on that, we need to create an array of `JSX` elements for `<Carousel element={this.state.currentCarouselElement} />`.

So what we need is for the `element` property of `Carousel` component is basically one array with a list of `JSX` elements. So I think based on that you can do just like the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // here we create an array with two JSX elements in an array
    this.state = {
      currentCarouselElement: [
        <div key="1">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/banner_1.jpg" alt="banner" className="rounded-top" />
          </a>
          <div className="bg-white rounded-bottom p-10">
            <span className="font-color-green font-weight-bold ">News article 1 text</span>
          </div>
        </div>,
        <div key="2">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/banner_2.jpg" alt="banner" className="rounded-top" />
          </a>
          <div className="bg-white rounded-bottom p-10">
            <span className="font-color-green font-weight-bold ">News article 2 text</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ]
    }
  }

  // removed other properties just for the example you can add them back
  render() {
    return <Carousel element={this.state.currentCarouselElement}
    />
  } 
}
```

Or the other solution can be using still `HomeCarouselComponent` just like this:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IHomePageCarouselProps> {
    return [
      <div key="1">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/banner_1.jpg " alt="banner" className="rounded-top" />
        </a>
        <div className="bg-white rounded-bottom p-10">
          <span className="font-color-green font-weight-bold ">News article 1 text</span>
        </div>
      </div>,
      <div key="2">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/banner_2.jpg " alt="banner" className="rounded-top" />
        </a>
        <div className="bg-white rounded-bottom p-10">
          <span className="font-color-green font-weight-bold ">News article 2 text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    ]
}
```

Please realize that the `render` function returns an array of `JSX` elements, semicolon separated:

```
[
   <div key="1"></div>,
   <div key="2"></div>
]
```

Additional info is that for each `JSX` elements you need to pass a `key` property just like I did for `<div key="1">`. I think inside of the `Carousel` component the `render` method uses `map` which requires `key` attribute for each rendered elements.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the efforts still I think you did understand my question or may be I am not good at explaining. I edited my question so this time you can understand my requirement

Comment: Hey, now I get it, changed completly my answer based on the documentation. Could you please try this solution and let me know if that gives you the idea or need further help? Thank you!

Comment: I like component approach but it give error Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<IHomePageCarouselProps, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>': type, props, key

Comment: Maybe you can try to pass `any` instead of `IHomePageCarouselProps` for `render`.

Answer (score 1):

For rendering a list of elements in React you can use React.Fragment

```html
      return(
       <React.Fragment>

        <div key="1">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/banner_1.jpg " alt="banner" className="rounded-top" />
          </a>
          <div className="bg-white rounded-bottom p-10">
            <span className="font-color-green font-weight-bold ">
              News title will show here. News title will show here. News title will show
              here. News title will show here. News title will show here. News title will
              show here. News title will show here. News title will show here. ...
                </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div key="2">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/banner_1.jpg " alt="banner" className="rounded-top" />
          </a>
          <div className="bg-white rounded-bottom p-10">
            <span className="font-color-green font-weight-bold ">
              News title will show here. News title will show here. News title will show
              here. News title will show here. News title will show here. News title will
              show here. News title will show here. News title will show here. ...
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>


      </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: well this was not question, I can understand that you make my component with array. But I was looking for output array of element as still your answer provide me 1 div

Comment: Edited the answer. Now it returns an array of elements